# how to call .exe file within c++ program?

Tags: c++

I want to use a exe file (convert.exe), inside my C++ program. This "exe" file change my output file format to another format. when, i use this convert.exe from my command-prompt (cmd), i have to type like this;

convert -in myfile -out convertedfile -n -e -h

where;

myfile=        name of the file, I obtain from my c++ program
convertedfile= result of the "convert.exe" file
-n, -e, -h =   are some parameters (columns) that i need to use to get output file with my
               desired data columns.

i tried with system(convert.exe). but, it does not work as i did not know how to use all those parameters.

Comment: Why does this have a c# tag when the question is about c++?

Comment: sorry, i wanted to get more comments

Comment: Attempting to steal attention by mistagging questions is not acceptable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function expects a `const char *`, so how about you try

`system("convert -in myfile -out convertedfile -n -e -h")`

Then, if you want to be a little more flexible, you use [`std::sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/sprintf) can create a string with the right elements in it and then pass it to the system() function like so:

```
// create a string, i.e. an array  of 50 char
char command[50];  

// this will 'fill' the string command with the right stuff,
// assuming myFile and convertedFile are strings themselves
sprintf (command, "convert -in %s -out %s -n -e -h", myFile, convertedFile);   

// system call
system(command);
```

Comment: can i modify this function to get different input file names and then to get different output files like (char* infile)

Comment: thank you. it works. how can i modify this code to link with any files like(char * filename), then i can use it or can recall if it is defined as a function when i need to convert my output. any help please.

Comment: @g_niro, I edited my answer to add an example code, hope that helps

Comment: Watch out for overflow here. sprintf will happily overflow the buffer if the file names are long enough to make the result larger than the command buffer. Use something safer for the composition, like concatenating std::strings.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Very much agree with you on this, but I thought it would be better to give the SO something easy to start with. Given the way the question was formulated, it sounded like he/she is a very much new at programming... and everyone should know what sprintf does even if it is risky to use

Comment: I disagree. As far as I'm concerned, a C++ programmer (the question is tagged C++) doesn't ever need to know what `sprintf` does. Perhaps `snprintf` (or is that the horribly broken function that doesn't null-terminate?) if he needs to use format strings and no alternative is available, but never `sprintf`, unless he is reading old code.

Comment: and the guys is clearly not a c++ programmer whether the questions says so or not

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [ShellExecute function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "<fully_qualified_path_to_executable>\convert.exe", 
                           "-in myfile -out convertedfile -n -e -h", 
                           NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Win32 API [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these:

```
int execl(char * pathname, char * arg0, arg1, ..., argn, NULL);
int execle(char * pathname, char * arg0, arg1,..., argn, NULL, char ** envp);
int execlp(char * pathname, char * arg0, arg1,..., argn, NULL);
int execlpe(char *  pathname, char * arg0, arg1,..., argn, NULL, char ** envp);int execv(char * pathname, char * argv[]);
int execve(char * pathname, char * argv[], char ** envp);
int execvp(char * pathname, char * argv[]);
int execvpe(char * pathname, char * argv[],char ** envp);
```

[exec() family of functions creates a new process image from a regular, executable file...](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/execl.3.asp)

Comment: It would be helpful to include a link to the page describing what each function does. I know google helps, but still...

Answer (score 1):

system (command); from stdlib.h

Since you don't want parallel execution wouldn't three consecutive calls to the execs with system () work for you?