# Calling g++ in c++ source code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, ide

So I already searched everything I could have. I'm writing my own IDE using C++ and I'm trying to find a way to call g++ or any other compiler. The only way I have thinked of so far is as such:

```
int main(){
   system("g++ --flags");
   return 0;
}
```

Do you guys know or can think of any other way to do this in c++?

Best regards,
Zé Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "raw" way is using your OS's API: the [`exec()` family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) on POSIX, [`CreateProcess[Ex]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows.

Quite often, you can also use this through a platform-independent abstraction. It's quite likely the toolkit you're using for GUI (whatever it is) already has process-launching functionality as part of its API. For example, Qt has [`QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html), wxWidgets has [`wxExecute()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__procctrl.html).

Comment: Any **cross-platform** way to do this? I'll look into the wxWidgets docs to see if it provides such function.

Comment: Thank you very much. The wxExecute function works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you're attempting to preserve the output from the command, you should use [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).  Its use resembles opening a file, and it can be used that way as well

```
FILE *compiler = popen("g++ --flags", "r");
```

then use the `fgets`, `fscanf`, etc `stdio` commands.  This will work find if you are targeting linux.
Here's a (fairly) more complete example

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    FILE *compiler = popen("g++ -Wall f.cpp -std=c++11", "r");
    char c;
    while (( c = std::fgetc(compiler)) != EOF) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way will work fine.  Here are some other ways to do it if you are interested: [how to call .exe file within c++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155537/how-to-call-exe-file-within-c-program)

Comment: I'm on linux so any win32 API commands or of the chart. On the system part I was always told that it is a bad practice so how do we stand in that topic?

Comment: @ZéPedro `system()` is in the C standard since C89, so if I were you, I would stop worrying about using it :-)

Answer (score 0):

system function call is blocking call. It will generally wait for the call to return if my understanding is correct.